# Relocated MySQL socket file to RAM

Tags: mysql, sockets

For over two years, I have been working on a project for my son where I use a Raspberry Pi 2 running Raspbian Jessie to control the speed of a blower in his attic.  The idea is to ventilate the attic to regulate the temperature on hot days while not over ventilating and wasting energy.  The blower control program has been running successfully for about a year now.  For most of the past year, I have been try to add a MySQL database to maintain 288 records of 10 parameters (one record every 5 minutes) for the past 24 hours so at any time, I can look at that data and see how the system has been performing for the past day.  Because the system runs continuously (24/365), I am concerned about the compact flash card life.  Because the data only covers the last day and recreates in a day, I am not worried about loss on power failure.
 At boot, I run a routine (Main.py) which copies the MySQL data file and blank table to RAM where MySQL works with it just fine.  Next, I have modified Main.py to place mysqld.sock and mysqld.pid in RAM.  I have modified the following items in /etc/mysql/my.cnf and in /etc/mysql/dedian.cnf as below:
/etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[client], [mysqld_safe]
Original:   socket      =  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock  
Modified:   socket      = /var/tmp/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
Original:   pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid        
Modified:   pid-file        = /var/tmp/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Original:   socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock       
Modified:   socket      = /var/tmp/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Original:   datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
Modified:   datadir     = /var/tmp/mysql/ControlData
        Note: ControlData is the name of my MySQL database

/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
[client], [mysql_upgrade]
Original:   socket      =  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock  
Modified:   socket      = /var/tmp/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

After performing the above modifications to /etc/mysql/my.cnf and /etc/mysql/dedian.cnf, now when I run BlowerControl, I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/RasPiConnectServer/local/BlowerControl.py", line 404, in 
    con = mdb.connect(host="localhost", user="ControlMonitor", passwd="02121945", db="ControlData")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in **init**
    super(Connection, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

It seems as though something is still telling MySQL to make the socket connection in /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock instead of /var/tmp/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.  I have done a great amount of searching and come to conclude that the problem may be to do with **kwargs2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py.  I have tried many changes here and elsewhere without success.

I will very much appreciate any help anyone can provide.  If anyone would like to help, I will gladly email my BlowerControl.py and Main.py programs.

Comment: Why do you care where the socket file is? Put it back. It's just a name. The data doesn't go through it.

Comment: My understanding is that the socket file is used as an intermediate storage location for transfer of data and that as such it is continually written to and read from.  If I am correct, having the socket file on CF card would mean potential wear and failure of the CF card.  Is my understanding incorrect?